# How to summarize two columns by the same categories

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with thousands of rows that has 3 columns (ID, Category at Intake, Category at Discharge). The categories are No Risk, Low Risk, Medium Risk, and High Risk.  I'd like to create a viz that compares the count of each category between the two columns Intake and Discharge.  So imagine a table with the following rows and 3 columns like this:

Category, Count Intake, Count Discharge

No Risk,            10, 20

Low Risk,           30, 30

Medium Risk,            20, 10

High risk,           5,  5

Total,                  65, 65

I can create separate visuals for both columns. I've tried creating a new table with ADDCOLUMNS and SUMMARIZE -- these give me the same result for both columns.

Table 2 = SUMMARIZE(Table1,Table1[Intake Classification],"Count Intake Classification",Counta(Table1[Intake Classification]))

I tried with SUMMARIZE and can create one column.  I'm stuck on the 2nd column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you add a new table (Modeling tab, New Table):

```
RiskCat = DISTINCT(Risks[Intake])
```

Next add two columns (Modeling tab, New Column):

```
Count Intake = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Risks;RiskCat[Category] = Risks[Intake]))
Count Discharge = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Risks;RiskCat[Category] = Risks[Discharge]))
```

End result:

[image]